# Calculating $E[(X-E[X])^3]$ by mgf

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

> Calculate by mgf $E[(X-E[X])^3]$ where
>
> a. $X\sim B(n,p)$
>
> b.$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$

Before I begin I thought symbolizing $Y=X-E[X]$ and then I'd derivative $M_Y(t)$ three times substitute $t=0$ and solve both questions but I'm not sure about the distribution of Y.

My question is "Does subtracting a constant changes the distribution of random variable $\sim B(n,p)\text{ or }  N(\mu,\sigma)$"?

**EDIT**:
I got $np(2p−1)(p−1)$ in binomial and 0 in normal. The next question is why the binomial tend to 0 as $n→∞$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it changes the distribution. For one thing, the mean changes by that constant. In the binomial case, the distribution is no longer binomial. In the normal case, the new distribution is normal, mean $\mu-c$, variance $\sigma^2$, where $c$ is the constant you subtracted.

We will look at the problem in two ways. The second way, which is the better way, uses the fact that the mgf of $X-c$ is a close relative of the mgf of $X$.

**First way:** One perhaps slightly painful but mechanical way to find the expectation of $(X-E(X))^3$ is to expand the cube. For simplicity write $\mu$ for $E(X)$. So we want $E(X^3-3\mu X^2+3\mu^2X-\mu^3)$. By the linearity of expectation, the mean of this expanded object is 
$$E(X^3)-3\mu E(X^2)+3\mu^2 E(X)-\mu^3.$$
Now all the missing bits can be picked up from the mgf of $X$.

**Second way:** Let $Y=X-\mu$, where $\mu=E(X)$.  Recall that the mgf of $Y$ is $E(e^{tY})$. This is $E(e^{t(X-\mu)})$, which is $e^{-t\mu} E(e^{tX})$.

We have found that the moment generating function of $Y=X-\mu$ is $e^{-\mu t}$ times the moment generating function of $X$.

Now for your two problems do this (i) Write down the mgf of $X$; (ii) Multiply by $e^{-\mu t}$. Now you have the mgf of $Y$. You can read off $E(Y^3)$ from the moment generating function of $Y$.

For the normal, the answer you get should not come as a surprise, since $Y$ is normal with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: With some minus signs.

Comment: Still typo fixing. Long process, I write too much.

Comment: Pardon for illteracy but still I'm not sure I understood the connection between $E[Y]$ and $E[Y^3]$

Comment: There is no close connection. We read off $E(Y^3)$ from the **mgf of** $Y$, maybe by taking the third derivative, or in some other way finding the coefficient of $t^3$ in the power series expansion of the mgf of $Y$.

Comment: so actually,$M_Y(t)=e^{-\mu t}M_X(t)$ and by deriving 3 times, and substituting 0, we get $E[Y^3]$?

Comment: Exactly. We do need $\mu=E(X)$, obtained from the mgf of $X$ or in some other way.

Comment: The third central moment is indeed $np(1-p)(1-2p)$ (I prefer this version, but it says the same thing as yours). The third central moment, as I mentioned at the end of my answer, is no surprise. By symmetry it is obviously $0$. But you were asked to compute it the long way! Of course the third central moment of the binomial does not approach $0$ as $n\to\infty$. A glance at your expression shows that. Probably the exercise is asking you to show that the **skewness** goes to $0$. The skewness is the third central moment, divided by the cube of the standard deviation. (More)

Comment: So it is what you got divided by $(np(1-p))^{3/2}$. That does go to $0$, easily verified. Informally it means that for fixed $p$ the binomial gets more and more symmetric as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: In two comments up, I meant the third central moment of the **normal** is no surprise.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is "Does subtracting a constant changes the distribution $B(n,p)$ or $N(\mu,\sigma)$"?

Well, of course it does... For example, $X$ is $N(\mu,\sigma)$ iff $X+c$ is $N(\mu+c,\sigma)$, hence $X-E[X]$ is $N(0,\sigma)$.

But this is not what you need to solve the exercise. Rather, you should first compute $E[X]$ and $M_X(t)=E[\mathrm e^{tX}]$, then $M_Y(t)=E[\mathrm e^{tY}]$. This last step is easy since $Y=X-E[X]$ hence $M_Y(t)=\mathrm e^{-E[X]t}M_X(t)$. Can you proceed from there?